# Can I use triggers to change value before insert if the type is wrong?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a column `CHAR(16)` and the inserted value to the table is longer then **16** characters. Can i create a trigger to do substring before insert ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trig
BEFORE INSERT ON example
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(NEW.test) > 16
    THEN
      SET NEW.test = substr(NEW.test, 1, 16);
    END IF;
  END;
```

Is this possible ? For now I am getting exception:
`[2017-11-02 15:28:22] [22001][1406] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'test' at row 1`

I am working with **MYSQL 5.7**